# H2 ignoring <div>s before that and Hover Bring border that change Other Elements' Position

Tags: html, css

> 

I have an h1 tag

then one div (inside this div there is 4 more div)

then another div(inside this div there is 2 image)

then I want to add an h2 tag but for some reason, it is ignoring those 2 div on top and starting just after the h1 tag.
how to fix this. If you see result images it will be clear. this is the first time I ask a question, please don't give me a negative mark. I am stuck with this problem for 50 minutes.

--

```css
.infoPastel {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 17px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  border-style: dotted;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.infoPastelBody {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 0px;
}

.pastelImg {
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 385px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 480px;
}

#pastelImg {
  position: relative;
}

.pastelVideoText {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden" id="myPastelPage">
  <h1>I am Pastel</h1>
  <div>
    <div class="infoPastel">
      <p><b>Name :</b></p>
      <p><b>Bate of Birth :</b></p>
      <p><b>Age :</b></p>
      <p><b>Species :</b></p>
      <p><b>Breed :</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoPastel infoPastelBody" style="border-right-style:double;">
      <p> Pastel</p>
      <p> 10/11/2015</p>
      <p> 4+</p>
      <p> Feline</p>
      <p> DLH</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoPastel" style="border-left-style:double;">
      <p><b>Colour :</b></p>
      <p><b>Sex :</b></p>
      <p><b>Desexed :</b></p>
      <p><b>City Council :</b></p>
      <p><b>Owner :</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoPastel infoPastelBody">
      <p> Black</p>
      <p> Female</p>
      <p> Yes</p>
      <p> Hume</p>
      <p> Amin</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pastelImg">
    <img class="images pastelImg " id="pastelImg1" src="Images/Pastel1.jpeg" alt="2020">
    <img class="images pastelImg " id="pastelImg2" src="Images/Pastel2.jpeg" alt="2020">
  </div>
          <h2 class ="pastelVideoText" > this h2  tag ignoring the images and the div before</h2>
          <h2>My Videos </h2><!-- here I want my h2-->
```

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFO58.jpg)

[CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1u2f.jpg)

[Result without hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15dEb.jpg)

[Result After hover the h1 tag changed its position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15GEm.jpg)

Comment: where do you want to add the h2 tags? why do all that stuff so complicated and not simply use a table for your project? much easier and less headache.

Answer (score 0):

First of all where exactly do you want to add the h2 tags?

Comment: After the div that contains the image. please see this "Result without hover" image.